# Simplest way to submit form through Enter key pressed from any form field?

Tags: forms, vue.js

To submit a form by pressing `Enter` key the standard solution is:

`<input v-model="name" v-on:keyup.enter="submit" />`

But what if a form has many input fields? Is it necessary to add `v-on:keyup.enter="submit"` to every single one of them, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: The standard way is rather to have a submit button and a `submit` event handler on the `form`.

Comment: I don't understand, on what element do you apply the `keyup.enter` in this case?

Comment: You don't need that at all. Forms have been submitted using the enter key for ages, even before JavaScript became popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should wrap the inputs in a form as follows:

```
<form v-on:submit="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, where do I put my `v-on:keyup.enter` though? The question is, how to avoid using `keyup` on every single field?

Comment: You won't need ``v-on:keyup.enter`` in this case. This listener applies to ``enter`` on all of its input children.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, has this always been the case or is it a recent Vue feature?

Comment: No, I don't think it is a new feature.